# Syntax for an alias

Tags: c

I'm looking at [LPSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230353%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) which is defined as

`typedef char* PSTR, *LPSTR;`

The documentation says that PSTR is an alias for LPSTR.  Is the fact that the dereference operator is missing enough to tell me it's an alias?  How are alias's declared?  In other words if I change this to

`typedef char* PSTR, PSTR2, *LPSTR;`

Do I now have two alias's?  What if I add another dereferenced variable?

`typedef char* PSTR, *LPSTR, *LPSTR2;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is missing. The whitespace around the asterisk doesn't matter.

This:

```
typedef char* PSTR, *LPSTR;
```

is the same as

```
typedef char *PSTR, *LPSTR;
```

which in turn is the same as having

```
typedef char *PSTR;
typedef char *LPSTR;
```

Both define type alisaes for the type "pointer to `char`", but there is no connection between them, the fact that they're both declared with the same `typedef` doesn't matter much, is mostly done when you want variants (with and without pointer) like so:

```
typedef struct {
  int x, y;
} Point, *PointPtr;
```

this, by the way, is a practice I *really* discourage (as is the code in the question itself), since "hiding the asterisk" is generally a bad idea. That asterisk *matters*, and having it present instead of being hidden in the type makes the code much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

What is meant by alias is that

```
typedef char* PSTR, *LPSTR;
```

is equivalent to

```
typedef char *PSTR;
typedef char *LPSTR;
```

so they're exactly the same type: aliases for `char*`. (The fact that you have to type the `*` twice in the first form is a quirk of C declaration syntax.)

Btw., these are not "dereferenced variables". They are pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef char* PSTR, PSTR2, *LPSTR;
```

PSTR is a pointer, LPSTR is a pointer but PSTR2 is a char.  I would write it differently:

```
typedef char *PSTR, PSTR2, *LPSTR;
```

To show where the * is really associated.